# Codeigniter base_url() function, go to parent folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I've an application working since one year, now my client is asking to make a folder outside the App to place the contracts (PDFs) in.

The point is that the app is fully working and has many calls to the `base_url()` function, so I cannot change the config file `$config['base_url']` variable or my app will stop working.

So basically I need to go to the parent folder of my current app.

Let's say the base url is at `www.mysite.com/a/app/` I need to go into the `www.mysite.com/b/` folder.

My first idea was:

```
<?= base_url('../b') ?>
```

But of course does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
echo base_url(array('.', '..', 'b'));
```

OR

```
echo base_url('./../b');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo base_url() . '../../b/';
```

Answer (score 0):

work for me

back to one folder;

```
dirname(base_url());
```

back to two folder ;

```
dirname(dirname(base_url()));
```